# Is it true that every discrete valued random variable can be written as a sum of indicators?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-variables

If $X$ is a rv which assumes values in a countable set say, $x_i\in C $.

We can always write $X=\sum_{i}x_i\mathbf{1}_{\{X=x_i\}}$ right?

And does a similar kind of decomposition exist for continious random variables?

Comment: Isn't $\sum_i \mathbf{1}_{ \{X=x_i\} }$ just equal to 1 with probability 1?

Comment: Yes you are right I edited it, I forgot the factor $x_i$ in front of the indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let some random variable $X$ such that $A:=\operatorname{img}(X)$ is countable, therefore
$$
X=\sum_{x\in A}x\mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(x)}
$$
However you cannot achieve a similar decomposition if $X$ have an image that is uncountable, by example when the probability distribution of $X$ is continuous. But in this latter case you can find a sequence of random variables $X_n$ with finite image such that $\lim_{n\to \infty }X_n(\omega )=X(\omega )$ almost sure, what means that the previous identity holds for a set of $\omega $ of probability one.

---

EDIT: well, there is a possibility to write every random variable as a kind of "sum" of indicator functions, indeed as an integral. You can see it [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295738/explicitly-representing-a-random-variable-in-terms-of-indicator-functions).

Comment: Note that physicists will often abusively view a random variable, even one with an uncountable image, as an infinite sum of indicators (or as an integral of indicators in some sense).

Comment: @Mark interesting... I didn't knew this possibility. There is a way to formalize it. I will add to the text of the body.

Comment: Thanks @Masacroso, Mark Saving!